# Two swagger URLs from single spring boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

I have a spring boot project, after running I can open the swagger URL.
I have mentioned two groups for my swagger:

1. External
2. Internal

I am looking for a way, where if I provide external API URL to customers, they will not be able to see internal APIs and vice versa.
Is there a way, we can have two different URLs for a swagger document?

Note: I am using springdoc-openapi-ui library for this.